# Antiderivative of a function arised in KdV equation

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

I am computing the third non-trivial conservation law of KdV equation $$u_{x}+6uu_{x}+u_{xxx}=0$$ via the power series expansion method (Here we consider real-valued solutions only).

I was given an equivalent form of the PDE: $$\left(2u^3+5u_{x}^2\right)_{t}+\left(36u^3u_{x}+6u^2u_{xxx}+10u_{x}u_{xxxx}+60u_{x}^3+60uu_{x}u_{xx}\right)$$

To finish the job one needs to express $$\left(36u^3u_{x}+6u^2u_{xxx}+10u_{x}u_{xxxx}+60u_{x}^3+60uu_{x}u_{xx}\right)$$ in a form $$(\cdots)_{x}$$.

It is clear that $(9u^4)_{x}$ is an antiderivative of $36u^3u_{x}$, but what is the antiderivative of $$6u^2u_{xxx}+10u_{x}u_{xxxx}+60u_{x}^3+60uu_{x}u_{xx}$$ in terms of derivatives of $u$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am fairly certain that this is an impossible task.

The $u_{x}u_{xxxx}$ term is okay because it can be produced by the following two terms:
$$
(u_x u_{xxx})_x = u_{xx}u_{xxx} + u_x u_{xxxx} \;\text{ and }\; (u_{xx}^2)_x = 2u_{xx}u_{xxx}. 
$$

Now consider
$$
(u u^2_x)_x = u_x^3 + 2uu_xu_{xx} \;\text{ and }\; (u^2 u_{xx})_x = 2uu_xu_{xx} + u^2 u_{xxx}.
$$
To produce the coefficients in your equation, using above two terms will leave out one term from 
$$u^2 u_{xxx}, \;uu_xu_{xx},\; u_x^3, $$
any of which don't have closed form antiderivatives.

To see this, we can use a qualitative argument. All of above terms have three copies of $u$, and totally 3 derivatives w.r.t. $x$. To find the antiderivative, we need three copies of $u$ and total 2 derivatives to distribute among three $u$'s, the only possible choices are $u u^2_x$ and $u^2 u_{xx}$. Thus to produce all three, the coefficients must satisfy certain relations.

The closest is:
$$
u (u u_{xx} - u^2_x/2)_x = u^2 u_{xxx}.
$$